# Digital signature in java

Tags: java, xml, digital-signature

I'm trying signature a xml, but have some problems.

The digital signature always appear in the end of file, I need add it to node father:

```
X509Certificate cert= (X509Certificate)keyEntry.getCertificate();        
KeyInfoFactory kif = fac.getKeyInfoFactory();
List x509Content = new ArrayList();
x509Content.add(cert.getSubjectX500Principal().getName());
x509Content.add(cert);
X509Data xd = kif.newX509Data(x509Content);
KeyInfo Ki = kif.newKeyInfo(Collections.singletonList(xd));

DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);            
Document doc;
doc = dbf.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new FileInputStream("E:\\HFACHO\\JAVA\\Netbean\\filejavaws.xml"));
DOMSignContext dsc = new DOMSignContext(keyEntry.getPrivateKey(),doc.getDocumentElement());
// ad namespace
dsc.setDefaultNamespacePrefix("ds");          
XMLSignature signature = fac.newXMLSignature(si, Ki);        
signature.sign(dsc);                         


//create output file
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream("E:\\HFACHO\\JAVA\\Netbean\\filejavaws_Firmado.xml");
TransformerFactory tf=  TransformerFactory.newInstance();
javax.xml.transform.Transformer trans = tf.newTransformer();
trans.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(os));
```

Comment: I found this good reference - http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-o-Simple

Comment: https://drive.google.com/a/integrens.com/file/d/0B8Ix7-GIED4eeXo3Z0pVZi1ycWs/view?usp=sharing here the code

Answer (score 0):

Well my approach, may not be very conventional, but it would be to take the signature node from the result and build a new xml with the signature node at the top

**UPDATE based on your comment:**

Well you have to decide if you are going to keep the signature where its generated and expected or if you want in at the beginning of the document.

The later approach could work if you are also responsible of the code that verifies your customs-process signature

http://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core/#sec-o-Simple

Comment: but that would not generate me that this signature is not consistent with the XML document?

Answer (score 0):

The solutions is simply:

```
dsc.setParent();
```